# Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'. Must declare the scalar variable "@Road"

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, scalar

While importing bak file to SQL Server, I am getting above messages.
I do not know where this error is coming from.

1. Is there a way to check where this @road is defined in my SQL DB?
2. How to declare scalar variable in SQL?//Standard declaration format

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Show us the problem code.

Comment: Can you give us more details on where in the DB restore process you see this error, during it or after it when you attempt to run something? If in the restore process itself, can you show us the code that you are using to restore the backup.

Comment: Yeah without the code this is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + f  and type in @road into the search box that appears in the top right.

General syntax for declaring a variable is

```
declare @varname vartype (varsize if needed) = value.
```

i.e.

```
declare @Road varchar (50) = 'Mike Rd.'
```